# How can stop sending emails SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

How can stop sending emails? I need to send emails to users but this creates a cycle infinity and I can't stop the emails sent, I'm sending emails with SES.

Right now SES are sending emails how can stop this?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't stop your application which sends the e-mails, you can revoke SES permissions from the IAM user. This way, your app (sender) will get rejected by SES.